# How can I run terraform init with azure on my local machine

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I'm trying to run terraform locally but it should connect to an azure machine. We have azure agents that do exactly this. If I run it locally, it would help me to move faster.

Here is my command

```
terraform init -reconfigure -backend-config ~/common.tfvars
```

Here is the error

```
    Initializing modules...                                                                                                                                                                                                                │··················································
    - module.kubernetes                                                                                                                                                                                                                    │··················································
    - module.database                                                                                                                                                                                                                      │··················································
    - module.trafficmanager                                                                                                                                                                                                                │··················································
    - module.appInsights                                                                                                                                                                                                                   │··················································
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        │··················································
    Initializing the backend...                                                                                                                                                                                                            │··················································
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        │··················································
    Error configuring the backend "azurerm": resource_group_name and credentials must be provided when access_key is absent                                                                                                                │··················································
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        │··················································
    Please update the configuration in your Terraform files to fix this error                                                                                                                                                              │··················································
    then run this command again.
```

cat ~/common.tfvars

```
    resource_group_name = "myproject-nst-config-RG"
    storage_account_name = "myprojectnstterraform"
    container_name       = "tfstatemyprojectact"
    key                  = "nstproject"
```

What am I missing? Is what I want even possible?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide credentials for Terraform to connect to Azure, usually a service principal, this will include username/applicationID, password and tenant. Have a read of the [MS documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/terraform-install-configure) on using Terraform with Azure and you will see they set environment variables with these details.

Comment: or pass the Storage account key (`access_key`) if the Service principal has no permissions on that storage

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to use the az cli login, you'll want to make sure you are running Terraform 0.12.